# UITextView dataDetectorTypes = .Link won't certain detect links

Tags: swift, datadetectortypes

The UITextView isn't editable, is selectable but can't detect links that end with .ph, .id, .in, .so, .to, etc

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

it works on other urls that end with .com, .org, .co, .net, etc

Comment: is `userInteractionEnabled ` is `true`?

Comment: Yes. it works on other urls

Comment: You should file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com. But I've heard some of these are intentional. For example ".so" and ".to" would be wrongly underlined if a sentence begins with "so" or "to" in English and the author of the text forgot the space after the dot. Same applies for other languages.

Comment: ohhhh okay, Thanks man. but is there any way I can add these link types inside NSDataDetectors ?